# MS CRM 4.0 Certain fields appear only if a certain answer is selected?

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, dynamics-crm-4

I would like to know if it was possible to make certain fields invisible until the question linked to them is selected to Yes. Then other fields pop up to go into more detail. I'm not sure if CRM can do this, but if so I would like to know how.

Comment: Sorry, can you repeat that? I did not hear you the first time. Perhaps try a bigger font.

Comment: Why are you writing everything in capital letters?

Answer (score 2):

On your onLoad function put the following

```
crmForm.all.field.style.display = 'none';
crmForm.all.field_c.style.display = 'none';
```

Then on the onChange event of the field you're monitoring put this to show the field:

```
crmForm.all.field.style.display = 'inline';
crmForm.all.field_c.style.display = 'inline';
```